# Detecting when button is clicked from the wrapper function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple script I use to filter some results on a click of a button.

This is how I call this script on every page I use it:

```
myScript();
```

And then the script is: (this is just the part of the script, in reality the script itself is a long script that does some more stuff before the button click)

```js
function myScript() {
       
  // .. other part of the script ..
    
  $("button.my-script.filter-button").on("click", filter)
    
  function filter() {
    let filters;
    // calculating the filters . . .
    // return filters;        
  }
}
```

I wanted to make this script work globally on every page that has it and trigger it on a click of a button with the classes `.my-script` and `.filter-button`. But then how can I detect when the `filter()` method was called and get the result conveniently?

Because when it's inside the wrapper I have no control over it (I want other people who need to use this script to be able to get the filters result without modifying the script code themselves)

Comment: Simply remove `function filter() {` from the click function and place it elsewhere. It's hard to tell how to help you specifically since you did not provided any simple yet specific [mcve]. What is `filter` ?

Comment: But let's say now another dev wants to use the script, so he places it on top: `myScript()`, how can he then listen for changes on the click button? Should other devs write themselves `$("button.my-script.filter-button").on("click", filter)`? I might have written the question in a confusing way. What I want is to allow other devs to access the `filters` result easily after initializing the script

Comment: It all depends if it's you who created dynamically that button `button.my-script.filter-button` and inserted it into the DOM, or it's devs job to create such a button. Either way, you could create a library that has a method like onFilter. If you want to allow your dev users to pass a custom selector to your script, than that's also a valid question. In such case your script should be able to accept a custom selector as argument

Comment: Because I want other devs to place the buttons wherever they want I don't create the button myself. In such case, should I attach the `$("button.my-script.filter-button").on("click", filter);` outside the script? so that every dev will add it below `myScript();` thus have access to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question provides no details on the way your script is supposed to work, how flexible it should be, should it be instantiated to provide independent instances, or as a singleton, whether you want to use a publish/subscribe pattern, or just use jQuery's `.trigger()` etc... In fact there are so many ways, all different in implementation and usage.

To stick as closely to your requirement and provided code, I suppose you just want to allow developers to use your script like `script()` - set and forget.

If that's the case, you might want to provide an `options` object argument with the desired methods that a developer can use like:

```js
function myScript(options) {
  
  const opt = Object.assign({
    selector: ".my-script.filter-button",
    onFilter: () => {},
  }, options);
  
  // ... other part of the script ...
  
  function filter() {
    let filters = [1,2,3]; // Calculating the filters...
    opt.onFilter(filters);
  }
  
  $(opt.selector).on("click", filter);
}

// Usage
myScript({
  onFilter: (data) => {
    console.log(`My filters are: ${data}`);
  }
});
```

```html
<button class="my-script filter-button">FILTER</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.js"></script>
```

Using the above, in the case a developer changes in HTML the button selector, he can then easily provide the new selector like:

```
// Usage
myScript({
  selector: "#myFilterButton",
  onFilter: (data) => {
    console.log(`My filters are: ${data}`);
  }
});
```

If the developer does not want to read the filters data, and is happy with the default parameters, he can still use your script in its minimal format like

```js
// Usage
myScript();
```

---

Learn more about different JavaScript patterns: https://www.patterns.dev/posts

Comment: This is a really good answer, with extra resources and explanation. It does what I wanted in a more neat way than I imagined (You did it in a way I didn't know before). thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the filter function from binded event and make it global ...And call same function in binded event

I hope this will help.